# Get special max record

Tags: vb.net

I have in my Table1 3 fields (IdFactory Type Numeric-IdSector Type Numeric-NameFactory Type Text).When i click on Button1 i get max record of (IdFactory) in TextBox1.My ComboBox1 is filled with several numbers from 1 to 100.I choose (IdSector) by ComboBox1 and the records in this field (IdSector) repeat only 5 times.How to automatically display max record of (IdSector) in combobox1 when i Click on Button1.this is my code to get max record on TextBox1

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteScalar` returns `Nothing`, not `DBNull.Value` if no result has been found.

```
Dim result As Object = Cmd.ExecuteScalar
Dim id As Integer
If result Is Nothing Then
    id = 1
Else
    id = CInt(result)  + 1
End If
TextBox1.Text = id.ToString()
ComboBox1.SelectedItem = id
```

This assumes that you have added the numbers to the ComboBox as `Integer` and not as `String`. If you have added them as `String` do `ComboBox1.SelectedItem = id.ToString()`.

Comment: Thank you very very much Olivier.very nice of you.My ComboBox1 is already filled by Table2 like this on Form1 Load .. I changed code in my post1

Comment: But records repeat always 5 times in field (IdSector) ... 1 repeat 5 times .. after number 2 repeat 5 times .. after number 3 repeat 5 times .. and so on .. please look at picture of Table1

Comment: Why are you not simply filling the combo box with `ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray())` or `ComboBox1.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray()`?

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice.But my problem is not in how to fill ComboBox1 .. My problem when I click Button1 how to display the special max records in Combobox1 as explained in my first post and in Table picture .Thank you Olivier.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you are trying to do. You can also add objects to a combobox. You might have to create a class with the required information. The you can configure [DisplayMember and `ValueMember](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/377224-combobox-displaymember-and-valuemember-winforms/).

Comment: Or maybe you need `SELECT DISTINCT somthing`?

Comment: No sir .. not this way with Select Distinct .. record in field (IdSector) repeat only 5 times

Comment: I change code in Button1 but i can save only 2 records .. and i have this message error(Changes not made: risk of duplicates in index fields, master key or relationship prohibiting duplicates. Modify the data of the fields containing the duplicates, remove or redefine the index to allow duplicates and start again.)..when i click on Button1 always i have number 2 in TextBox1 when i want save the third record

Answer (score 0):

Keep your data objects local so you can be sure they closed and disposed. The Using...End Using blocks do this for you even if there is an error.

What I think you are after is the IdSector for the highest IdFactory. Although you can't use an aggregate function in a where clause; you can use a sub-query with an aggregate.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim result As Object
    Using Conne As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
        Using Cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select IdSector from Table1 Where IdFactory = (Select max(IdFactory) From Table1);", Conne)
            Conne.Open()
            result = Cmd.ExecuteScalar
        End Using
    End Using
    If result Is Nothing Then
        TextBox1.Text = "1"
        ComboBox1.Text = "1"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = (CInt(result) + 1).ToString
        ComboBox1.Text = result.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Mary .. I change code in Button1 by your code but i can save only 2 records .. and i have this message error(Changes not made: risk of duplicates in index fields, master key or relationship prohibiting duplicates. Modify the data of the fields containing the duplicates, remove or redefine the index to allow duplicates and start again.)..when i click on Button1 always i have number 2 in TextBox1 when i want save the third record

Comment: I didn't see any code with an Insert statement. I am sorry I couldn't help but I really don't understand what you want to do. If you had your IDFactory set as the Primary Key of Table1 and it was an auto increment field you would not have to worry about duplicating a primary key. What is IdSector in real world terms?

Comment: (IdFactory) is my primary key and (IdSector) is Type Numeric..I have teams and each team must only have 5 members.I choose number of team (IdSector) by ComboBox1.when i save records by Button2 (IdFactory) will add 1 each time in the usual way ..But (IdSector) will add 1 each 5 records .. i put code for save in my first post.